# Can you use less then the rated current on a High Side Smart Switch such as BTS555

Tags: power, mosfet, power-electronics

I often see Minimum Current listed on the data sheets of some Smart Switches, Power distribution Switches etc.

For example in the data sheet of BTS555 it states that the minimum current is 128A so does that mean my load should be at least this value? Could I not use it to switch a load of 10A or evan 1A?

Comment: This "minimum" is the *worst possible* performance of the device, based on their design/manufacturing. It's an *upper* limit for the user of the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the switch for lower currents. When they list the load current as having a "minimum" of 128A what they mean is you are "guaranteed" that the device will be able to drive up to that minimum current and keep working (provided you follow the other specs for temperature/power/etc.). Some devices may perform better than that and safely drive more current, but they don't guarantee any higher than that value.

Comment: Ok thats what I thought, Would there be any adverse affects of switching low currents such as 1A (apart from the waste of a high value part)? Also how could you calculate the maximum current if you just use pin 3 for Vbb